# How to replace the Zebble SignaturePad UI Component or add and use another SignaturePad component?

Tags: xamarin-zebble, zebble

Using Visual Studio, when selecting 'Zebble for Xamarin - Cross Platform Solution' a default project will be created with five pages. I've modified the fifth page to implement a signature pad. Below is the following `Page-5.zbl` code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<z-Component z-type="Page5" z-base="Templates.Default" z-namespace="UI.Pages"
    z-partial="true" Title="About us" data-TopMenu="MainMenu" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./../.zebble-schema.xml">

  <z-place inside="Body">

    <TextView Text="Hello world!" />
    <SignaturePad Id="sigPad1" Enabled="true" LineThickness="4" Style.Border.Color="red" Style.Width="100" Style.Height="100"/>

  </z-place>

</z-Component>
```

Which ends up adding this line to `.zebble-generated.cs`:

```
    await Body.Add(sigPad1 = new SignaturePad { Id = "sigPad1", Enabled = true, LineThickness = 4 }
    .Set(x => x.Style.Border.Color = "red")
    .Set(x => x.Style.Width = 100)
    .Set(x => x.Style.Height = 100));
```

I have been looking at this SignaturePad component package: https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad

If I wanted to use the Xamarian SignaturePad component or anyone else's SignaturePad component instead of the Zebble SignaturePad UI component, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a third party component, all you need to do is to create a Zebble wrapper around it. It's explained here:
http://zebble.net/docs/customrenderedview-third-party-native-components-plugins

**Step 1: Creating Native Adapter(s)**

You should first create a Zebble view class to represent an instance of your component using the following pattern. This class will be in the Shared project, available to all 3 platforms.

```
namespace Zebble.Plugin
{
    partial class MyComponent : CustomRenderedView<MyComponentRenderer>
    {
         // TODO: Define properties, method, events, etc.
    }
}
```

**Note:** To make the VS IntelliSense in ZBL files recognize this, you should create a .ZBL file for MyComponent as well:

```
<z-Component z-type="MyComponent" z-base="CustomRenderedView[MyComponentRenderer]" z-namespace="Zebble.Plugin"
    z-partial="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./../.zebble-schema.xml" />
```

The next step will be to create the renderer classes.

**Step 2: Creating Native Renderers(s)**
You need to create the following class each platform (UWP, iOS, Android).

```
 public class MyComponentRenderer : ICustomRenderer
  {
        MyComponent View;
        TheNativeType Result;

        public object Render(object view)
        {
            View = (MyComponent)view;
            Result = new TheNativeType();
            // TODO: configure the properties, events, etc.
            return Result;
        }

        public void Dispose() => Result.Dispose();
}
```

**Using it in the application code**
In the application code (App.UI) you can use MyComponent just like any other built-in or custom view type.

```
<Zebble.Plugin.MyComponent Id="..." Property1="..." on-Event1="..." />
```

Comment: I currently have the folder/file solution layout structure that is created by default when creating a new `Zebble for Xamarin - Cross Platform Solution`. Regarding step 1's text, "this class will be in the Shared project," what do you and/or Zebble's documentation define the Shared project as? So that I may understand where you're advising me to create the class. I have reviewed the website and only see definitions for `App.Domain` and `App.UI`.

Comment: Both App.Doman and App.UI projects are "shared source" project types in visual studio and any code in those logically also "exists" in the platform specific runnable projects (UWP, Android, iOS).

Comment: In your case App.UI is senantically the right place to write the code.

Comment: Will I need to add an element to `.zebble-schema.xml`? When adding it to the application code, I get an "element not declared" message.

Comment: No .zebble-schema.xml is automatically overwritten and re-generated from the .zbl files in your project. Instead of creating just a class, in the above example if you create a ZBL file for MyComponent then the schema file will be automatically updated to recognize it.

Comment: Thank you, it may be a good idea to add that to the website documentation as well.